# Access Denied when browsing a user profile Organization

Tags: my-site

I am in an environment that crosses between two Domains.  The First domain has user profiles and mysites (although the mysite feature is disabled).  The People search is used to find organizational members and information about them pulled from AD (Active Directory.

The second Domain users have access to the first domain but do not have profiles.  Users from the second domain can browse the profiles of users in the first domain, but when they click to expand the organizational structure they get an access denied.

While the MySites (profiles) and the Organizational structure reside on different web applications, they both have the same permissions (such as Domain\NT Authenticated User).

What is causing the Access denied?  Do you have to have a profile inorder to view the organizational structure of other profiles?

Comment: They need to be Domain Users on the first domain in order to see profiles on it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE Craig! You have a very good question, which interests me too. Are you using [ADFS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/30/configuring-sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-v2-end-to-end.aspx), or are you just using two different domains in different User Profile Services? If you can add more information on how your user identification provider(s) work together, it will be easier to give a more accurate answer to your question. Nice to see you here!